# Import existing table into SQLite and generating a scaffold command for Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activescaffold

I have a rather large MS Access table with about 50 fields and would like to know if there is a way to create a scaffolding command without typing it out by hand, I can export the whole table into SQLite with no problems but i have several of these tables from a legacy system and it would probably take me a day to type out all of the commands.

Answer (score 0):

Did it the hard way ;) all by hand done the trick...